# Is there a FileType name for files without suffix in vim?

Tags: vim

With my current knowledge, I can use command like `autocmd FileType markdown colorscheme zen` to set colorscheme for particular type of file.
Now I have a need to use a colorscheme for all those files without suffix.
Such as `no_suffix_file`.

I did some research online, but didn't find relevant infos.
I guess there maybe a name for this kind of files in vim, at least a name for all the other files that are not in vim's `FileType detector range`.

What's it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you put in your `vimrc` is what's used for every buffer, *including* buffers with no `filetype`, unless there's an `ftplugin` that overrides your generic settings.

One way to work around the problem would involve at least one autocommand and a function:

```
function! MyColors()
    if &filetype == ""
        colorscheme noft
    elseif &filetype == "foo"
        colorscheme foo
    elseif &filetype == "bar"
        colorscheme bar
    else
        colorscheme baz
    endif
 endfunction

 augroup colors
     autocmd!
     autocmd BufNewFile,BufEnter * call MyColors()
 augroup END
```

Note that colorschemes are global anyway so I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: I know the default colortheme is for every filetype. But I got this need. First, I got a default colortheme for everything except markdown. And I made a specified colortheme for markdown. But I found another need after, that I need to make a colortheme for raw-text-files(files without suffix), that's why I came here. In short, this `files without suffix` type should be in on of the `elseif` statement on your function above.

Comment: `files without suffix` is covered by the first condition.

Comment: and this `&filetype == ""` statement is no way to express in `autocmd FileType "" colorscheme zen` form?

Comment: No, hence the function.

Comment: I'm not sure `filetype` is _always_ sat at the time `BufEnter` is run.  Perhaps add a `BufReadPost` to the list, to make it safer.

Answer (score 0):

When Vim *can* determine a file's type from a file extension, it will. For example, files whose name ends in ".c" will almost always be C-language files, so Vim sets the "c" filetype.

Files without an extension, however, can literally be of any type at all. They could be makefiles, configuration files, shell scripts...

*Some* file types can be determined by their contents, even if they have no extension. For example, scripting language files (perl, python, etc.) as well as shell scripts will often have a "hashbang" line telling the shell what program to invoke to interpret the script. Vim can use this line as well, to determine the filetype. Other file types have other distinguishing characteristics.

See `:help new-filetype-scripts` for details, and the file `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim` for examples (and the files detected by Vim from contents in a default installation).

If no file type is detected from file extension, and no file type is detected from file contents, then Vim will not assign *any* file type, and the `'filetype'` option will be empty. romainl's answer shows how to detect an empty filetype.